# Does SQLite DB erase on App Update in .NET MAUI?

Tags: .net, sqlite, maui

I'm developing an app using .NET MAUI and SQLite for both Android and iOS platforms - And they'll be published on their stores.

The DB is entirely created during execution of the project - For example, this is where I create my tables:

```cs
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

public static class SQLConn {

        private static readonly string DBName = $"dba.db";
        private static readonly string ConnectionString = $"Data Source={DBName};";

        public static void CreateDatabase() {

            string[] databasesToCreate = new string[]
            {
              "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"car_list\" ( \"car_id\" INTEGER UNIQUE, \"car_manufacturer\" TEXT NOT NULL, \"license_plate\" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, \"date_purchase\" TEXT, \"price_purchase\" REAL, \"using_km\" INTEGER NOT NULL, \"km_purchase\" INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(\"car_id\" AUTOINCREMENT) )",
              "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"user\" ( \"user_id\" INTEGER UNIQUE, \"user_name\" TEXT UNIQUE, \"password\" TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(\"user_id\" AUTOINCREMENT) )",
              "",
            };

            using (var conn = new SqliteConnection(ConnectionString)) {
                conn.Open();

                foreach (string createCommand in databasesToCreate) {
                    using (var command = new SqliteCommand(createCommand, conn)) {
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                conn.Close();
            }

        }
 }
```

Everytime I recompile my app, I lose all information stored inside my DB.

Does it means that every update that I launch in the stores, all data are lost? If so, how can I make an backup to restore when the user updates the app?

Comment: Store the database in a better place

Comment: No, it should not replace existing files on relaunch

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the application, you will need to determine if the current database exists, rather than create a new one.

For this, you can check the official document [.NET MAUI local databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-8.0).

And there is an official sample about this, you can check it here: [.NET MAUI - Local Database with SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/database-sqlite/).

You can test that this problem does not happen when the app is restarted.